# Controlling mouse wheel by code

Tags: c, windows, scroll, mouse, mousewheel

I'm trying to develop a program that scroll a text page.
I need to control the mouse wheel by code. How can I do it?

Comment: In Windows or Linux? And what type of control?

Comment: In windows. I just need to scroll down and up the mouse wheel.

Comment: Do you try to react when the user scrolls the wheel? Or do you want to scroll as if the wheel was used but when it was in fact not used? Answerers seem to have understood you differently on this detail.

Comment: Why has it to be done by emulating a mouse?  Consider that you can make it a lot more reliable by bypassing the mouse handling in the program you target and produce the end result, send the WM_VSCROLL message.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the SendInput function from the WINAPI (user32.dll).

**Pseudo**

```
UINT ScrollMouse(int scroll)
{
   INPUT input;
   POINT pos;
   GetCursorPos(&pos);

   input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
   input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL;
   input.mi.time = NULL; //Windows will do the timestamp
   input.mi.mouseData = (DWORD)scroll; //A positive value indicates that the wheel was rotated forward, away from the user; a negative value indicates that the wheel was rotated backward, toward the user. One wheel click is defined as WHEEL_DELTA, which is 120.
   input.mi.dx = pos.x;
   input.mi.dy = pos.y;
   input.mi.dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();

   return SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Install [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):**

```
pip install pyautogui
```

Sample :

```
import pyautogui
x = 100
y = 100
pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

Another Sample :

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 150)
pyautogui.moveRel(0, 10)  # move mouse 10 pixels down
pyautogui.dragTo(100, 150)
pyautogui.dragRel(0, 10)  # drag mouse 10 pixels down
```